# AWS Lambda Consumes time when uploading files to S3 using node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

My program on lambda works as it starts by fetching the file from twilio with the help of url and then it stores it on my /tmp in lambda then that file is uploaded to aws S3 from lambda's /tmp . My concern is that if its a large file say 200MB then for that time lambda runs for a lot of time . Is there any way of stopping the lambda while it is uploading to s3 and then wakes when s3 upload is completed successfully. And can similar concept possible for downloading so that lambda could stop and when file is uploaded to /tmp it wakes and does the uploading of file to the AWS S3 . That can save a lot of time

Comment: The container running the Lambda has to be active when you're doing any of those actions, so it can't "sleep" and then come back afterward, and uploading and reading from the container requires execution time. You might have a use case that is suboptimal for Lambda if this happens a lot and your code ends up running significantly long each time.

Comment: If you stop the lambda, the upload stops.

Answer (score 3):

The hard drive where `/tmp` exists and the CPU that is processing the upload/download and the memory needed for buffers used by the upload/download... are provided by the **running** Lambda container that is processing the transfer.

The fact that you have access to these resources is exactly because you are paying for a **running** Lambda container.

If it were possible to stop it from running, or pause it, you would have no access to those resources, and the upload/download would stop happening.

This isn't possble.

Comment: there isn't any api that would download the file directly to s3 without lambda being in between them . Just the api callling and url passing in lambda and the rest will be handled by api ?

Comment: There is no API request that you can make to Amazon S3 to direct it to fetch content externally.  It is possible to request S3 to fetch and copy content from another S3 bucket (or the same bucket) if your account has permissions on the source object, but this is still a synchronous/blocking API call -- you have to remain connected while waiting for the response.

Comment: Michael , that means there is no way i can send data to s3 bucket from public url , until and unless i have a ec2 server or any server intermediate ?

Comment: Other than using Lambda, of course, that is correct.  I have contemplated creating a service that could do this on user's behalf, but I haven't come to a conclusion on how much demand there might be for such a service... sort of an asynchronous transfer service that would respond immediately and give you a follow-up URL to poll for status, or fire a webhook back to you when the transfer is complete.

Comment: i was trying to find an external third-party api to transfer data from a public url to AWS s3 , the request with the url will be transferred from my AWS lambda so that lambda will not store the file on to /tmp , rather the api will do all the processing of saving and transferring of the file to S3 . Since Lambda will run alot of time for saving in '/tmp' , then transferring it to s3.